# Prove distance function is bijective

Tags: functions, proof-writing, inverse

For a pair of points $p_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $p_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ define $$d(p_1, p_2) = \sqrt{ (x_1 - x_2)^{2} + (y_1 - y_2)^{2} }$$ the distance between p1 and p2. Then the function f satisfies $$d(f(p_1), f(p_2)) = d(p_1, p_2)$$ $\forall p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Prove that $f$ is a bijection, thus it has an inverse.

---

So I know a bijection is an injecction that is also surjective. I.e., a mapping which is both one to one and onto.

So to prove it's injective I believe all we need to do is basically set $d(p_1, p_2) = 0$ then show that, that implies $p_1 = p_2$?

To prove its surjective I'm having a little more trouble conceptualizing. If anyone could help that would be exceptional.

Comment: You are misstating the problem. Please check. Surely, the intended problem is to show that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: You mean to show that $f$ (not $d$) is a bijection.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I shall make the correction. Thanks guys!

Comment: Rather than just edit it, why not take a cut at the corrected problem?

Comment: I wasn't asking for help because I thought it was d I had to prove. It was simply a typo, my question is more about proving the surjection with this type of function.

Comment: Hints:$\;(1)\;$Applying the triangle inequality, show that $f$ bijectively maps lines to lines (i.e., _full_ lines to _full_ lines);$\;(2)\;$Using the Pythagorean theorem, show that $f$ maps perpendicular lines to perpendicular lines;$\;(3)\;$Deduce that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of considering perpendicular lines, consider parallel lines.